# Identify the position for particular element using jquery

Tags: jquery

How to identify the x axis and y-axis of particluar element using jquery. Like we use pageX and pageY to identify the mouse pointer's position.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using [`offset()`](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/offset).

> ```
> var p = $("p:last");
> var offset = p.offset();
> p.html( "left: " + offset.left + ", top: " + offset.top );
> ```

Answer (score 2):

there is `position()` function that return `Object{top,left}`

```
var p = $("p:first");
var position = p.position();
var left = position.left;
var top = position.top;
```

Comment: position() is relative to the offset element not the page (like pageX and pageY on events). offset() is the better fit here.